# Redirect root path on root domain to subdomain

Tags: seo, redirects, subdomain

Say there's a web application that runs on `example.com`, would there be a penalty for 301 redirecting the root of the domain (`example.com/`) to `subdomain.example.com` for purposes of hosting the marketing website for an application? Obviously we would expect `subdomain.example.com` to be what is ranked in the search engine, not `example.com`.

We would want other paths on `example.com` like `example.com/path/to/resource` to index normally, and be unaffected by the 301 on the root path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fine to do that if that is what you wish.

Not really sure what else to add as this is a relatively common practice and if implemented correctly, there are no negative repercussions from this.