# Redirect root domain to path

Tags: domains, redirects, domain-registrar, domain-forwarding, path

Searched all questions by *redirect* keyword (e.g. [1](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1441/is-there-any-way-to-redirect-one-domain-to-another-via-dns-settings-keeping-the), [2](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/63227/redirect-root-path-on-root-domain-to-subdomain)) but none of them fit my case.

I want to redirect my domain (`www.example.com`) to another (sub-)domain including path and query if possible:

```
www.lokki.newdomain.com/resources/index.html?crsource=google&category=web
```

I do not host second domain website and since that I have no access to its configuration.

My registrar allows setting up domain forwarding but only mirroring one:

```
example.com/resources/index.html -> newdomain.com/resources/index.html
```

and I want to set up redirect from my root directly to document.

Is there a way?

**UPDATE**: having in place AWS instance, what would be the most effortless way of implementing such redirect?

Comment: Redirecting requires a web server.  It isn't possible to redirect without having some minimal amount of hosting.  In other words, it isn't possible to redirect with just DNS.

Comment: Ok, and such service as Cloudflare that was mentioned? It can be useful?

Comment: I also have AWS Linux instance, how to set up such redirection with minimum effort? Could you point out some documentation? Updated the question and removed no-hosting requirement

Comment: You referred to both `www.example.com` and `example.com` in your question - note that these are different hostnames and consequently _both_ will need to be configured in your AWS instance if you wish to _redirect_ from both.

Comment: Use https://redirect.center

Comment: This URL doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a DNS A record to point the domain to the IP address of your Linux instance.   Assuming that the instance is running Apache, you would then create a virtual host that does this redirect:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    ServerName example.com
    RedirectMatch ".*" "https://www.lokki.newdomain.example/resources/index.html?crsource=google&category=web"
</VirtualHost>
```

You don't say what Linux distribution you are running, so where this configuration needs to go can be a bit different.   On Debian based distributions such as Ubuntu or Mint it would go in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf` then you would use the commands `sudo a2ensite example.com` and `sudo service apache2 reload` to enable it and load the configuration into the already running server instance.

Using Nginx, the [syntax would be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045020/how-to-redirect-to-a-different-domain-using-nginx) the following, but I'm not sure which file it would go in.

```
server {
  server_name .example.com;
  return 301 https://www.lokki.newdomain.example/resources/index.html?crsource=google&category=web;
}
```

Comment: I'm running AMI Linux, Amazon's fork of CentOS. Can nginx also be an option?

Comment: Sure, Nginx can do it.  I edited some config into my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I've successfully configured redirection, it works. Can you please suggest how to do so that original URL is showed in address bar (`www.example.com`), not target long URL? Tried `proxy_pass` and `rewrite` but that didn't work

Comment: You would have to use `proxy_pass` across host names.  However, I don't know nginx well enough to answer that.  You should probably ask another question here about it.  Specifically, I don't know how you would proxy all wildcard URIs to a specific page on the other server.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway

Answer (score -2):

Cloudflare Webworkers or Nginx reverse proxy redirection could be worth a shot.

Comment: Such a short answer is not high quality.  Can you explain how to use those?   It would also be helpful to link to documentation for them.