# Redirecting in NGINX with masking target URL

Tags: redirects, nginx, configuration, masking

I've set up redirection on NGINX with the help of [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/126008/redirect-root-domain-to-path) and now I want to set up it with hiding redirection from user, i.e. keeping original `example.com`.

Things I've tried:

[rewrite](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html)

```
server{
    server_name .example.com;
    rewrite ^/$ www.lokki.newdomain.com/resources/index.html permanent;
}
```

[proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html):

```
server{
    server_name .example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass www.lokki.newdomain.com/resources/index.html;
        proxy_set_header Host      $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      }
}
```

but none of them worked.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?